# Find duplicate rows in SQL with column type having text

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, duplicates

I have a table with sturcture as below.

```
ID          bigint Primary key
StudySysID  bigint Foreign key
ContentText text    
PageCount   int 
StatusID    int 
...
CreatedOn   datetime
LastUpdated datetime
```

I need to find duplicate `ContentText` with same `StudySysID`. If a `StudySysID` has more than one row with same `ContentText`, Select all rows with that `StudySysID` except the latest one (Last one can be identified by `CreatedOn` OR `ID`).

I have tried this.

```
SELECT ID, StudySysID, CreatedOn, LastUpdated, StatusID, ContentText 
FROM RP_TblStudyDetails  
WHERE StudySysID IN (SELECT StudySysID
    FROM RP_TblStudyDetails  
    GROUP BY StudySysID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) 
AND ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID
    FROM RP_TblStudyDetails  
    GROUP BY StudySysID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )   
ORDER BY StudySysID DESC, ID DESC
```

It selects all duplicates of a `StudySysID`, but some of them have different content text which I don't want to select. I don't know how to check duplicate `ContentText` along this.

Comment: try with CTE and ranking function

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s: Will consider that for sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for all records where a newer sibling exists. So use the EXISTS clause.

```
select *
from rp_tblstudydetails sd
where exists
(
  select *
  from rp_tblstudydetails newer
  where newer.studysysid = sd.studysysid
  and newer.contenttext = sd.contenttext
  and newer.createdon > sd.createdon
);
```

EDIT: As can be seen from the comments below, the data type TEXT cannot be compared thus. Two possibilities to overcome this:

1. Change TEXT to VARCHAR(MAX) - this is the preferred solution.
2. Use `substr(newer.contenttext, 1, 1000000) = substr(sd.contenttext, 1, 1000000)` or whatever value other then 1000000 makes sense to you. SUBSTR(TEXT) returns VARCHAR.

Comment: I am getting an error: The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: IMHO this will filter out only the oldest rows but return more than one if there are e.g. three or more of the same. Maybe do a "NOT EXISTS any newer"?

Comment: @Roland: *All* duplicates except the latest. Isn't this what is being asked?

Comment: @Rohith: Ah, I didn't know about TEXT datatype in SQL Server. You cannot compare TEXT. The type is even deprecated and it is recommended to change it to VARCHAR(MAX). Can you do that? Here is the link telling so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Sorry, I cannot do that, as a lot of applications rely on this database.

Comment: If you can state a max length for content, you may try something like: `substr(newer.contenttext, 1, 1000000) = substr(sd.contenttext, 1, 1000000)`. SUBSTR(TEXT) returns VARCHAR.

Comment: Max length for content is below 100000 till now.

Comment: Some rows are still missing. For example, studysysid 551909 is having 5 rows of which 2 are duplicate. This query is fetching only 1 row instead of 2.

Comment: This is strange. Look at the query. It does exactly what you ask. So either there must be a (tiny) difference in content or the createdon is exactly the same, so both records are "latest". Please examine your data.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: You are right, On comparing the texts using a tool, I found a small difference. Word *this* was replaced with *the* in content. I have updated the answer with SUBSTRING(contenttext, 1, 1000000). Thanks.

Comment: Please update the answer. I updated the answer, but was rejected after peer-review.

Comment: Okay, I have done so. Your edit was rejected because it altered the answer. Using substr(contenttext, 1, 1000000) worked for you, but may not work for others. (It doesn't when one cannot name a sensible max length for content.) So comparing content directly is the preferred solution, but then TEXT would have to be changed to VARCHAR(MAX).

Answer (score 1):

Try this(untested)

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT dense_rank()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY StudySysID, SUBSTRING(ContentText, 1, 1000000)
                    ORDER BY CreatedOn desc) DR ,
                ID,
                StudySysID,
                CreatedOn,
                LastUpdated,
                StatusID,
                ContentText
         FROM   RP_TblStudyDetails)
SELECT *
FROM   cte where DR!=1
```

Comment: I got this error: The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator. I changed the `ContentText` to `SUBSTRING(ContentText, 1, 1000000)` as suggested by Thorsten.
Still some rows are missing. For example, studysysid 551909 is having 5 rows of which 2 are duplicate. This query is fetching only 1 row instead of 2.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is also correct after replacing `ContentText` to `SUBSTRING(ContentText, 1, 1000000)` as suggested by Thorsten. Thanks for the help.